# No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [TLS handshake failed: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate

Tags: mongodb, ssl-certificate

i`m trying to connect mongodb to php application from compose to local,but get this error.
but i can remote using mongo chef

**No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [TLS handshake failed: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed calling ismaster**

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 3 options to solve this problem.

## 1. Disable SSL on your server

Find `mongod.conf`, if you're using linux, then normally it should locate at `/etc/mongod.conf`, use `#` to comment these lines under `net`. Finally, you need to restart `mongodb` for making change works.

`net:
   ssl:
      mode: requireSSL
      PEMKeyFile: ./mongodb.pem
      ...`

## 2. Use the option called `weak_cert_validation` on your client

*This is not a safety solution, but this is definitely one of the simplest one*.

For example, if the mongoDB server has enable SSL but without (or did't) offering CA certificate(means self-signed certificate), then set `weak_cert_validation` as `true` in the client side, a example for C client:

```
mongoc_ssl_opt_t ssl_opts = {0};
ssl_opts.weak_cert_validation = true;
mongoc_client_set_ssl_opts(client, &ssl_opts);
```

## 3. Follow [configure-ssl](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/) to create a certificate and get it signed for your program.

Here some provider: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority#Providers